# Is it possible to remotely connect through 2 router?

Tags: networking, router, fritzbox

I've my main router responsible for my internet and another deviced called cubeX (https://www.daytradetheworld.com/cube-x/). I think you might treat this as a second router? But I'm not sure because I wasn't able to find any IP address for it, maybe there is?

What works is: I connect router 1 to that cubeX (router 2) and then go to the internet. But I need to access this from my working computer remotely, so without physical access to it. I was able to connect remotely to router 1, but not router 2.

- Is it possible to remotely connect over both routers and if so, how?
  Please explain it for stupid people like me, thank you in advance.
- How can I identify the router 2 in my network?

[image: Topology]

Comment: DTW offers no technical info about this device whatsoever at least without registering, which I'm not about to do. From what I can see from the website this is a financial appliance - that's **not** something to connect directly to the internet. For your own security it has to be firewalled and access to it tightly controlled. Due to the specific nature of the device and the lack of public documentation I suggest you contact DTW directly for advice.

Comment: If your computer is on Windows, can you see the CubeX in Explorer under Network? (Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)

Comment: Thank you for your help @harrymc. I see 4 different devices under network. Tried unplugging the cubeX and plugging it again. There wasn't any changes under "network", so I assume it can't be found there.

Comment: Thank you for your help @Peregrino69. Unfortunately, contacting the vendor is not an option. Yes, it's a financial appliance. It's not directly connected to the internet, but it gives me access to certain web pages. I don't understand this sentence: "For your own security it has to be firewalled and access to it tightly controlled."

Comment: Your pic names CubeX as Router 2 and it's directly connected to the internet. I assume your Router 1 is a regular ISP router, which has a firewall. So if CubeX is inside the router, it's not directly connected but is firewalled. And tightly controller access basically just means keeping the method you use to connect to it including obv. passwords to yourself. As it's somehow connected to trading, it's related to your finances, and protecting your finances is a part of your own security :-) I'm surprised if the device doesn't come with detailed how-to instructions.

Comment: According to your schema, the CubeX acts as a switch. It's unclear how it's to be used at all if it doesn't show up as a device or has an IP address. Do you have a manual that you can share?

Comment: Thank you @Peregrino69. I appreciate. Sure, but I want to connect remotely to that trading platform with my own credentials. There is a description how to use it at my own home network but not how to access it from the outside

Comment: thank you @harrymc. I really appreciate your help. Sure, I can share the instructions; https://postimg.cc/gallery/6qhYcZf. That's all I got how to use it. Maybe it can be found under "network" but I am just unable to spot it. Kinda unsure what to exactly look for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The device whose instructions you shared is not a router.
It needs to connect to your router and it gets a local IP address and is
addressed by a client program that you download from
[PPro8 Download](https://www.ppro8wiki.com/client/).

But the device itself is just one more device connected directly to
the router, just like your computer, and is then available on the
local network.

The device presumably enables the client software to extract data
from various trading platforms, which the client displays in useful
formats.

The device is not intended to be used from outside the local network.
You will need to remotely login to your computer in order to launch
and use the PPRO8 software program.

Comment: harrymc was faster :-) Adding to this: if you have installed the client it should connect automatically. If it doesn't connect or your username/password isn't accepted, you really need to email the Implementation Team. There's really not much anyone without intimate knowledge of a specialized device like this can do to help you further. For example connecting to it remotely from your office requires creating port forwarding rule on your router, but what that port should be isn't public information.

Comment: Thank you. just RDP into it sounds like a good solution!!